# MySQL - How to set variable value inside select statement?

Tags: mysql

I want to get the value of the previous row, current row, and add them. If there's no previous row then I'll just set previous to 0. Here's what I tried.

```
SET @previous = CASE WHEN (SELECT MAX(value) FROM table WHERE dateTime < '2018-07-01') IS NULL 
THEN 0 
ELSE (SELECT MIN(value) FROM table WHERE dateTime BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2018-07-30') 
END;

SELECT @previous AS Previous, 
@previous:=MAX(value) AS Current, 
(@previous + MAX(value)) AS Joined
FROM table 
WHERE dateTime BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2018-07-30'
GROUP BY dateTime;
```

Here's the table content:

```
dateTime   | value 
2018-07-01 | 1
2018-07-01 | 1.2
2018-07-02 | 1.7
2018-07-03 | 2.1
2018-07-05 | 2.6
2018-07-05 | 3
2018-07-06 | 3.5
```

Unfortunately setting @previous:=MAX(value) does not change @previous value for the next row, if it's 0 in initialization, it will remain 0. Sample Result:

```
dateTime   | Previous | Current | Joined
2018-07-01 | 0        | 1.2     | 1.2
2018-07-02 | 0        | 1.7     | 1.7
2018-07-03 | 0        | 2.1     | 2.1
2018-07-05 | 0        | 4       | 4
2018-07-06 | 0        | 4       | 4
```

Expected result

```
dateTime   | Previous | Current | Joined
2018-07-01 | 0        | 1.2     | 1.2
2018-07-02 | 1.2      | 1.7     | 2.9
2018-07-03 | 1.7      | 2.1     | 3.8
2018-07-05 | 2.1      | 3       | 5.1
2018-07-06 | 3        | 3.5     | 6.5
```

Hope you can help me!

Comment: flip previous and joined: `SELECT @previous:= @previous + MAX(value) AS Joined, 
(@previous - MAX(value)) AS Current` or just `MAX(value) AS Joined`

Comment: @The Scrum Meister - Same result :(

Comment: You need to group into a subquery first, see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b00f9/5)

Comment: Could you explain why the first group **2018-07-01** you expect *1* as current and not *1.2* which is the max for this group?

Comment: Oh my bad. should be 1.2

Comment: I updated my answer, here is a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b00f9/6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to first run the `GROUP BY` statement in a subquery, and only then run the variable calculation:

`` SELECT dateTime,
  @previous AS Previous,
  @previous + MaxVal AS Joined,
  @previous := MaxVal AS Current
FROM (
  SELECT `dateTime`, MAX(`value`) AS MaxVal
  FROM `table`
  WHERE `dateTime` BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2018-07-30'
  GROUP BY `dateTime`
) grp
ORDER BY `dateTime` ``